# Using LINQ to select EF properties in DBSet with specific Attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, attributes

Is there a way to perform a LINQ query on Entity Framework DBSets and only return the properties that have a specific custom attribute?

My goal is to perform a query and return only the properties/columns that I need for an export.

I also want to make this an extension for IEnumerable as I have many separate EF Classes that will use this export attribute.

This is how I am visualizing it:

```
public class Person
{
    [Export]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Export]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Export]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [NeverExport]
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
}

public void main()
{
    var people = PersonRepository.GetAll();
    var exportResults = people.GetByAttribute(ExportAttribute);
{

public static IEnumerable<object> GetByAttribute(this IEnumerable<object> list, Attribute attribute)
{
    return list
        .Select(x =>
           // Select properties with { attribute } (ie. [Export])
        );
}
```

Comment: So you could build up the expression manually, but that would be extremely complex code, and you'd still end up with an object with empty properties. It would be better to do this manually and use a DTO of some sort with only the properties you need, perhaps using something like AutoMapper to handle the mapping.

Comment: Why `GetByAttributes` has `list` parameter as `IEnumerabe` but not `IQueryable`? It is more effective to do that on `IQueryable` and do not request unwanted data from Database.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv My code was just to help visualize my goal, not so much what I am exactly doing. As to only getting what I want from the DB, that is my goal here. I only want values from the properties with the attribute.

Comment: Good to know that you are worrying about DB performance. I'll prepare solution tomorrow. But you have to notice, I have to return `IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>` or  to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a very basic example for your problem. In short, you want to get all Properties, where a specific Attribute is present. You can achive this via reflection. First, you want all properties of a specific type, then only the properties, where a specific attribute is present.

Here is my example code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var attrs = typeof(User).GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(y => y.GetType() == typeof(Custom)));

            var users = new User[] 
                {
                    new User() { ID = 1, Name = "John", Lastname = "Doe" },
                    new User() { ID = 2, Name = "Jane", Lastname = "Doe" } 
                };

            foreach(var u in users)
            {
                foreach(var attr in attrs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(typeof(User).GetProperty(attr.Name).GetValue(u, null));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Custom]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Custom]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }

    public class Custom : System.Attribute
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am looking how to select the VALUES of the properties to create a table.  I just want to return the properties or columns that have the attribute.

Comment: I think i understand, you can access the property values also via reflection. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code projects any IQueryable to `IQueryable<ExpandoObject>` and you can use it for exporting data. Additionally code caches projection expression for reusing later in application.

Usage is simple:

```cs
var exportResult = anyQuery.ProjectForExport().ToList();
```

And implementation:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ExportAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

```cs
public static class ExportTools
{
    private static readonly ConstructorInfo _expandoObjectConstructor =
        typeof(ExpandoObject).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    private static readonly MethodInfo _expandoAddMethodInfo = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetTypeInfo()
        .GetRuntimeMethods()
        .Single(mi => mi.Name == nameof(IDictionary<string, object>.Add) && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    public static class ProjectionCache<T>
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, ExpandoObject>> ProjectionExpression { get; } = BuildProjection();

        private static Expression<Func<T, ExpandoObject>> BuildProjection()
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a is ExportAttribute)).ToList();

            if (properties.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type '{typeof(T).Name}' has no defined Export properties.");

            var expr = (Expression)Expression.ListInit(
                Expression.New(_expandoObjectConstructor),
                properties.Select(p =>
                {
                    var readerExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, p);
                    return Expression.ElementInit(_expandoAddMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(p.Name), readerExpr);
                }));

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, ExpandoObject>>(expr, param);
            return lambda;
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<ExpandoObject> ProjectForExport<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.Select(ProjectionCache<T>.ProjectionExpression);
    }
}
```