# EF Core - projections as string

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to create an API which lets query all fields and relations' fields (transitively) of an entity.

Let's see through an example, using from EF-demo Students-Courses-Ennrollment data model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro

The following HTTP request would request 3 fields (I hope the syntax is understandable):

`GET /students?$select=FirstName,Ennrollments(12345).Grade,Ennrollments(67890).Course.Title`

Then the corresponding query would be something like:

```
context.Students.Select(s => new
{
  s.FirstName,
  s.Ennrollments.First(e => e.EnnrollmentId == 12345).Grade,
  s.Ennrollments.First(e => e.EnnrollmentId == 67890).Course.Title
});
```

So I'd dynamically map string field "references" to projections/EF expressions. Is this something possible to achieve with EF Core? For example using Metadata?

Comment: Yes it is possible, problem here that it is needed to generate dynamically class. Maybe `ExpandoObject` is better solution for projection.

Comment: Is it really your requirement? Maybe you could use OData queries for your case? Have a look on https://www.odata.org/getting-started/

Comment: @Serhii Yes, this is a requirement, or more precisely this is an actual working system and with many other features (expressions can be in "Where" or used to update data, used also in a webapp and desktop app for arbitrary column selection for lists). API is built over Swagger + OData.

The data layer is just "manually" composing SQL which works, but would like to if we could use the benefits of EF (Core). Now all OR/M should be done manually, which'd come "free" from EF and much more (ie. scaffolding, migrations, validation, etc.)

Could you please maybe direct me to a more precice guid?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Could you please maybe direct me a demo or sample?

Comment: This is my sample how to [project to ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69009848/10646316) For sure your have to change what to project.

Comment: I've ended up shifting towards Graph QL instead of OData. I'm aware of OData also supports expand, but find Graph QL syntax much more readable / intuitive