# Questions about Expression<Func<ExpandoObject, object>> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

known conditions:

```
public class ListSearchImportFieldModel
{
    public string Field_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to implement the following method
Return properties of `ListSearchImportFieldModel` as properties of ExpandoObject function as follows:

[image]

The incoming object (`ExpandoObject`) may have 100 attributes, I only need a few attributes specified in the list (`ListSearchImportFieldModel`).

Who can help me out, thank you very much!

I tried to let chatgpt do it for me, but it didn't work

Comment: Please post your code as *text*, not as an image. Also, please explain what you expect to happen. Show a [mcve] with your expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: I originally provided the code but couldn't submit it.I don't know what to do, I can only upload pictures

Comment: I have no time to make full answer till Monday, but here is similar [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69009848/10646316) which needs tweaking for your case.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply, I will learn about that post first

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include all of your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a little bit changed signature of the method and for now it accepts IEnumareble of field names and returns `Expression<Func<ExpandoObject, ExpandoObject>>`.

```cs
public static class ExpandoUtils
{
    static readonly ConstructorInfo _expandoObjectConstructor =
        typeof(ExpandoObject).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    static readonly MethodInfo _expandoAddMethodInfo = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetTypeInfo()
        .GetRuntimeMethods()
        .Single(mi => mi.Name == nameof(IDictionary<string, object>.Add) && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    static readonly PropertyInfo _indexer = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>)
        .GetDefaultMembers()
        .OfType<PropertyInfo>()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(object))
        .Select(p => new { p, parameters = p.GetIndexParameters() })
        .Where(t => t.parameters.Length == 1 && t.parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(string))
        .Select(t => t.p)
        .Single();

    public static Expression<Func<ExpandoObject, ExpandoObject>> CreateProjectionLambda(IEnumerable<string> fields)
    {
        var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ExpandoObject), "source");

        var inits = fields
            .Select(f => Expression.ElementInit(_expandoAddMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(f), Expression.Property(sourceParam, _indexer, Expression.Constant(f))));

        var exprBody = Expression.ListInit(
            Expression.New(_expandoObjectConstructor),
            inits);

        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<ExpandoObject, ExpandoObject>>(exprBody, sourceParam);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could convert `ExpandoObject` to `Dictionary` and conveniently create new `ExpandoObject` based on just created `Ditionary` by simply checking keys:

```
var props = new[] {"a", "b"};
var eo = new ExpandoObject();
eo.TryAdd("a", "z");
eo.TryAdd("b", "y");
eo.TryAdd("c", "x");

var dictFromEo = eo.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
var newExpando = new ExpandoObject();
Array.ForEach(props, prop =>
{
    if(dictFromEo.TryGetValue(prop, out var value))
    {
        newExpando.TryAdd(prop, value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this one doesn't get the result I want